# How to return a pair reference to data in a custom container?

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, containers, std-pair

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

class SimpleMap {
 public:
  typedef std::pair<const uint32_t, const uint32_t> value_type;
  static const int SIZE = 8;
  uint64_t data_[SIZE];
  SimpleMap() { data_ = {0}; }
  // Returning a reference to the contained data.
  uint64_t const& GetRawData(size_t index) {
    return data_[index];
  }
  // Would like to return a pair reference to modified data, but how?
  // The following wont work: returning reference to temporary
  value_type const& GetData(size_t index) {
    return value_type(data_[index] >> 32, data_[index] & 0xffffffff);
  }
};
```

Containers such as `map` has iterators that returns a reference to a pair. But how does that even work? If I am writing an iterator to a container, I need to return references to values. But how do I do that if the values are in pairs? And what if I need to slightly modify the data in creating that pair, as in the example above?

I hope my question isn't too confused. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not storing pairs so you cannot return a reference to your stored pair. Return by value instead.

If your array was `value_type data_[SIZE];` you could of course return references to these pairs - then you'd need to construct the `uint64_t` for `GetRawData` on demand, and return *that* as a value rather than a reference.

Comment: Ah, so obvious. It all makes sense now. I mistakingly assumed some of the containers I've seen stored their elements in more complex ways and used some magic to return pair-references. But of course, they just actually store pairs.

Comment: How map is returning a pair without storing data as pair?

Answer (score 3):

If you are returning modified data (rather than something directly stored in the container), then you cannot return a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here, check out [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/).  In a map, the pair is a mapping of the key to the value:

```
std::pair<KeyType,ValueType>
```

So you can access the value by:

```
ValueType value = pairPtr->second;
// or
ValueType value = pair.second;
```

Returning references to a value to modify later is simple, here's an example:

```
const size_t arSize = 8;
pair<int,int> arrr[arSize];

int& value = arrr[0].second;

value = 9;

int returnedValue = arrr[0].second;//you'll notice this equals 9
```